# Google Spreadsheet API with Android

Tags: android, spreadsheet, gdata

Anybody here using Gdata client library for Google Spreadsheet API. If yes how did u implement  OAuth for V3. Please supply me with sample code and demos.
thanks in advance..

Comment: Any special reason of using OAuth on Android when you can simply use Android Account Manager to get authentication code?

Comment: @Sharj bro how to do this.. i gotta no idea.. could you please explain me in detail .. thanks in regards.